# Google Translate Removes lines which has rem as a unit of measurement from the stylesheet

Tags: css, google-translate

I am trying to build a Google translate friendly site, however it seems lines which use rem as a unit of measurement are being removed. Is this because Google is yet to recognise rem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google has fixed this problem.